# Is this way logical to Update Layout Page (Has No Controller) and Normal Page With Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to update, my Layout page ( has Partial Page ) and my normal page which is connected to the layout page, with new datas from database.

HomeController -> Index.cshtml ( The page is getting data from database in the controller )

_Layout.cshtml ( The page has no controller. I have to get data from database in this page )

Is this way true and useful ?

***_Layout.cshtml (Layout Page)***

```
@{
       Layout = null;
       // Layout has no controller. So, i have to get database connection here
       ProjectName.Models.NewsContext db = new ProjectName.Models.NewsContext();
}

<!-- Menu_Section-->

// The data i've taken is being sent to P_MenuBar.cshtml partial page

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/P_MenuBar.cshtml", db.Categories)

<!-- /Menu_Section-->
```

---

***P_MenuBar.cshtml (Partial Page)***

```
@model IEnumerable<webprogramlamaodev.Models.Category>
```

`@foreach (var item in Model)
{
        @ActionLink(item.Name, "CategoryNews", "News", new { id = @item.Id }, null)
}`

---

***Index.cshtml***

```
// the data came from controller
@model IEnumerable<webprogramlamaodev.Models.News>

..
..
..
```

My English is not very well. So, sorry for my wrong sentences.

Comment: Never put database access code in a view. If you want to include a partial view in your layout so its shown in all views, use `@Html.Action()` to call a controller method that returns your partial (and in that method populate the data)

Comment: I've done. Thank you so much.